# Android Studio — хождение по мукам

Tags: android-studio, linux-mint

Извините за длинный текст, но может кому-то пригодится описание найденных решений.
Итак, 32-разрядная машина, Linux Mint 18.2, Android Studio 3.0.1.

**Установка:** 
Скачал с Оракла jdk1.8.0_144. Команды терминала

```
java -version
```

и

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

показывают, что с джавой и переменной среды все в порядке.
Рекомендации по установке Android Studio: https://itsfoss.com/install-android-studio-ubuntu-linux/ не работают, дают ошибку при установке пакетов. Скачал архив с официального сайта.

Android Studio не запускается с иконы, ругается на переменную среды. Командой терминала

```
/yourPath/studio.sh
```

запустить можно.

**Решение**: команды терминала (измените для вашего пути к jdk):

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /yourPath/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java  
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /yourPath/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac  
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /yourPath/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javaws
```

Создал новый проект с шаблона Empty Activity, не ввел ни буквы своего кода. Gradle быстро завершается ошибкой:

```
Gradle sync failed: Process 'command '/home/vlad/opt/android-
studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

**Решение**: File — Project Structure — SDK Location — сбросил флажок Use embedded JDK и ввел путь к jdk1.8.0_144.

Процесс Gradle идет дальше. Выводится IDE error:

```
Entry fileTemplates//Singleton.java.ft not found in 
/home/vlad/opt/android-studio/lib/resources_en.jar
```

Хотя на самом деле этот файл в указанном архиве есть.

**Решение**: в файл *android-studio/bin/studio.vmoptions* добавил строку:

```
-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false
```

Пустой проект загружается уже без ругательств от Event Log и Gradle Console, но символ R не распознан. Попытка Rebuild дает ошибки gradle build:

```
...tools/26.02/aap2: syntax error ….
```

**Решение**: Project Structure — app — Build Tools Version: поставил 27.0.3
Compile Sdk Version: поставил API 27.

Rebuild дает еще две ошибки. 
В файле *gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties* : изменил строку (старый вариант закомментирован):

```
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-all.zip
```

Одна ошибка ушла. Event Log говорит:

```
Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 13s 106ms
```

Gradle Console дает такое пояснение:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request.
```

Ну и, само собой, символ R не распознан.

**Вопрос**: кто знает как справиться с этой ошибкой?

Спасибо всем, кто дочитал до конца.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса должен содержать **краткую суть проблемы**, а не ваши переживания от нее. Видимо, нет ответа от сервера. Gradle должен скачать библиотеки из интернета, без этого проект не соберется. смотрите, что там с доступом в инет для студии, наверное.

Comment: Менеджер обновления студии работает, пакеты достаточно шустро загружаются. Спасибо за реакцию.

Answer (score 0):

Попутно: установил андроид студию, последнюю версию для 32-разрядной винды, под Win7.
И тоже не мог справиться с массой глюков.

**Проблема решилась так**: обновил комп, установил 64-разрядную Windows и соответствующую версию AS 3.5.3. Запустил шаблонный проект. Все работает.
**Вывод**: 32-разрядные версии под Линукс и под Виндовс кое-как компонуются и не имеют технической поддержки.